# Retrieve bit string from NEOS

Tags: cplex, operations-research, neos-server

I am trying to solve an LP file[(Link to google drive if you would like to try it)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MjKxmCI8wfZwSC35YuVsC2qxihg0F3I3/view?usp=sharing) via CPLEX on the NEOS servers. I can find the objective value quite easily, that being 9.200000000000e+01. However, I am also looking for the bit string to let me know the actual values of each variable. I don't see any options on the server for me to receive a bit string in the printed results, and when I check the email sent I don't get any sort of solution values there either. I do see an option for a solutions file, but how to use that is beyond me. I tried to upload a blank .xsd file there after reading some of the CPLEX documentation from IBM, but that did nothing as far as I could tell.

Did I miss some step in the LP file? Or is there no way to find a bit string from NEOS?

Thanks as always for any help that you can offer, it is greatly appreacitated!

Comment: Never used this service, but reading [item 22](https://neos-guide.org/content/FAQ) and [submission form](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/lp:CPLEX/LP.html) i would really guess it's not more than checking `Return .sol file`. Then i guess you should be able to login later to download the file (if it's not already part of the email). | Did you do the same? Where did you deviate (selecting LP; checking return sol box)?

Comment: Gah! I totally overlooked the return .sol file option! I was so stuck on inputting my own file that I did not check that box. Thanks for the help!